# C# Deserialize JSON data

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON

```
{{  "action": "rma",  "devices": "[95001105,30013103,300117]",  "devandreason": [    {      "device": 95001105,      "reason": 100    },    {      "device": 30013103,      "reason": 300    },    {      "device": 300117,      "reason": 200    }  ]}}
```

for which I'm trying to get the `devandreason` as an array.
I've tried creating classes

```
public class DevReasonList
    {
        public List<DevReason> devandreason { get; set; }
    }
    public class DevReason
    {
        public Double device { get; set; }
        public Double reason { get; set; }
    }
```

and the `json_serializer`:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
DevReasonList deviceAndReasonList = json_serializer.Deserialize<DevReasonList>(json.devandreason);
```

but it throws an exception:

> `json_serializer.Deserialize<DevReasonList>(json.devandreason)    'json_serializer.Deserialize<DevReasonList>(json.devandreason)'
>   threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'   dynamic
>   {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}`

But I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

It is possible to deserialize `devandreason` and make it an array?

Comment: Check out json2csharp.com. It's quite helpful when deserializing json.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: Any specific reason you have quotes between [95001105,30013103,300117] ?

Comment: The devices list has integer values. That's what I'm receiving in the controller after calling Ajax with json.stringify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be your model according to

```
public class Devandreason
{
    public int device { get; set; }
    public int reason { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string devices { get; set; }
    public List<Devandreason> devandreason { get; set; }
}
```

I removed the beginning { and trailing } and it now validates

```
{  "action": "rma",  "devices": "[95001105,30013103,300117]",  "devandreason": [    {      "device": 95001105,      "reason": 100    },    {      "device": 30013103,      "reason": 300    },    {      "device": 300117,      "reason": 200    }  ]}
```

Bonus: http://json2csharp.com/

Edit: 
As raised by @Sven in the comments:   RootObject would be so much easier to traverse if your devices type was List.

Here is the json that would be required, I just removed the quotes before the value:

```
{  "action": "rma",  "devices": [95001105,30013103,300117],  "devandreason": [    {      "device": 95001105,      "reason": 100    },    {      "device": 30013103,      "reason": 300    },    {      "device": 300117,      "reason": 200    }  ]}
```

Comment: sweet sweet link.

Comment: Why is "devices" not a List<int>?

Comment: Nvm I just noticed the quotes around the []

Comment: @Sven, you raise a good point however, If the Json could be changed to remove the quotes, then this model would be a lot easier to traverse.

Comment: Probably a mistake of his or something very specific on his part.